# Error in my Java code

Tags: java, syntax-error

I've got a problem with my Java program. There is an error in my code on line 16 (`t = T[i];`) which implies an error on line 12. It says :

```
Syntax error on token "=",VariableInitializer expected after this token.
```

Could I have some help ?

```
public class Ngrams {

    public static boolean estPrefixe(String t, String s) {
        int Longs = s.length();
        if (t.substring(0, Longs) == s) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int nbOccurences(String[] T, String s) {
        int compteur = 0;
        String t = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < T.length; i++) {
            t = T[i];
            if (estPrefixe(t, s)) {
                compteur++;
            }
            return compteur;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is line 12 and 16?

Comment: Please don't compare string using `==`, use proper case

Comment: The code compiles fine for me. BTW estPrefix appears to be the same as `String.startsWith`

Comment: There was a `}` missing. I may have accedently fixed the code when trying to fix the formatting.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:  Yeah, you did accidentally fix the code.  Give me a moment and I'll fix the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding the fact that you're comparing Strings with `==` instead of `.equals()`, and that a right bracket seems to have gone AWOL, at the end of your program, you're "missing" a return statement in `nbOccurences`.  Even though you have one in the for-loop, if you never enter the loop, you don't return anything.

Move your return statement down one line, outside of the loop instead.

```
public static int nbOccurences(String[] T, String s) {
    int compteur = 0;
    String t = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < T.length; i++) {
        t = T[i];
        if (estPrefixe(t, s)) {
            compteur++;
        }
    }
    return compteur;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `nbOccurences` does not always return an `int` value. If `T` is null or empty (length = 0) no value is returned. So you should add another return statement after the `for` loop.

As others mentioned already you should use `equals` to compare strings. This however, is not producing a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's a serious bug in this line:

```
if (t.substring(0, Longs) == s) {
```

This test will always be false, because == compares object references, not values. Change it to:

```
if (t.substring(0, Longs).equals(s)) {
```

But the whole method is pointless. Change it to:

```
public static boolean estPrefixe(String t, String s) {
    return t.startsWith(s);
}
```

Or just delete the method altogether because it adds no value whatsoever.

Comment: "This test will always be false" - this is not always true. If `t` and `s` are the same object than result of this equation will be `true`. In the same time, yes, topic starter should always use `.equals` instead of `=`.